# How to dynamically change event sources?

Tags: events, dynamic, fullcalendar

I am using the jQuery [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) plug-in. I want to load initially the calendar with events as an array. I am doing this like:

```
events: <%= Model.Events %>
```

or

```
eventSources: [{
                 events: <%= Model.Events %>
              }]
```

Both ways work fine. I am using MVC 3.0 and `<%= Model.Events %>` returns an array of events in JSON format.

I want to use the events array ONLY for the initial loading of the calendar. Later, every times events are needed to be fetched, I want my events to be loaded using the url '/Calendar/Events'.

How can be this implemented?

I tried difference scenarios with `addEventSource/removeEventSource` in the `viewDisplay` callback, but nothing worked fine for me.

Comment: Did you get this working? The answer below does not work. refectchEvents() is not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
.fullCalendar( {

  eventSources : [ {
    url : '/Calendar/Events',
    type : 'GET'
  } ],

  viewDisplay : function( event ) {
     // assuming this will point to the full calendar,
     // might have to do something silly like
     // $( '#myCal' ).fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' );
     this.refetchEvents();
  }
} );
```

Comment: Do you have a working example of this? refectchEvents() does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a very old question but I needed this right now. The answer wasn't here but I found it in another question.

Here what is solution.

My primary source of events is this(this is the events source from the default examples of Fullcalendar):

```js
events: function(start, end, callback) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'myurl',
                dataType:'xml',
                crossDomain: true,
                data: {
                    // our hypothetical feed requires UNIX timestamps
                    start: Math.round(start.getTime() / 1000),
                    end: Math.round(end.getTime() / 1000),                  
                    'acc':'2',                      
                },
                success: function(doc) {                            
                    var events = [];
                    var allday = null; //Workaround
                    var Editable = null; //Workaround  
                    $(doc).find('event').each(function() 
                    {                       
                        if($(this).attr('allDay') == "false") //Workaround 
                                allday = false; //Workaround 
                        if($(this).attr('allDay') == "true") //Workaround 
                                allday = true; //Workaround
                        if($(this).attr('editable') == "false") //Workaround 
                                Editable = false; //Workaround 
                        if($(this).attr('editable') == "true") //Workaround 
                                Editable = true; //Workaround                       

                        events.push({
                            id: $(this).attr('id'),
                            title: $(this).attr('title'),
                            start: $(this).attr('start'),
                            end: $(this).attr('end'),                       
                            allDay: allday,
                            editable: Editable
                        });                             
                    }); 


                    //calendar.fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', othersources.folgas );
                    //calendar.fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', othersources.ferias );       
                    //calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');               
                    callback(events);
                }
            });     
        }
```

Now i needed it to add more sources and to do this ouside the calendar (next to the date variables from fullcalendar examples) i made a variable like the code above, but with ajax calls similar to my primary: )

```js
var othersources = {

   anothersource: {               
            events: function(start, end, callback) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'myurl',               
                data: {
                    // our hypothetical feed requires UNIX timestamps
                    start: Math.round(start.getTime() / 1000),
                    end: Math.round(end.getTime() / 1000),                  
                    'acc':'7',                      
                },          
                success: function(doc) {    

                    var events = [];
                    var allday = null; //Workaround
                    var Editable = null; //Workaround  
                    $(doc).find('event').each(function() 
                    {                       
                        if($(this).attr('allDay') == "false") //Workaround 
                                allday = false; //Workaround 
                        if($(this).attr('allDay') == "true") //Workaround 
                                allday = true; //Workaround
                        if($(this).attr('editable') == "false") //Workaround 
                                Editable = false; //Workaround 
                        if($(this).attr('editable') == "true") //Workaround 
                                Editable = true; //Workaround                       

                        events.push({
                            id: $(this).attr('id'),
                            title: $(this).attr('title'),
                            start: $(this).attr('start'),
                            end: $(this).attr('end'),                       
                            allDay: allday,
                            editable: Editable
                        });                             
                    });                         

                    callback(events); //notice this
                }
            });     

        },                
            cache: true,
            //error: function() { alert('something broke with courses...'); },
            color: 'green', //events color and stuff
            textColor: 'white',
            //className: 'course'
       }     
 }
```

Now, he build diffrent sources and use like this both...

```js
eventSources: [ othersources.anothersource ],           

viewDisplay: function(view) {    
        if (view.name == 'month'){      
            calendar.fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', othersources.anothersource );
            //calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents'); 
//Notice i'm not doing the refetch events. And its working for me. but i'm calling thi elsewhere, every time i make an action. So you must figure it out ;)           
}
```

[Link to above solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940182/change-fullcalendar-event-source-after-render)

And another way i found on github.

Basically the problem was that I can't change data parameters after calendar initialization. For events this worked:

```js
    events: {
      url : '',
      type: 'POST',
      data: function () {
        return {
          action: 'view',
          search_text: search_text
        };
      },
      error: function() {
        alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
      },
      color:     '#31b0d5', // a non-ajax option
      textColor: '#fff;',   // a non-ajax option
    },
```

for resources it didnt so I had to make like that:

```js
    resources: function(callback) {
        var view = $("#calendar").fullCalendar("getView");
        $.ajax({
        url: "",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        data: {
          start      : view.start.format(),
          end        : view.end.format(),
          timezone   : view.options.timezone,
          action     : 'projects_employees',
          search_text: search_text
        }
      }).then(function(resources) {
        callback(resources);
      })
    },
```

Simple ways like that do not work cuz are static and couldn't be changed after init:

```js
events: {
      url: '',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
          action: 'view',
          search_text: search_text
      }
},
resources: {
      url: '',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
          action: 'projects_employees',
          search_text: search_text
      }
}
```

[Here is the github link. Replied by **peon501**.](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/4324)

After to many try, i did solve my problem with use first part (stackoverflow) codes. The key for me defiying eventSource with "var" key and use it like this

```js
//...
eventSources: [ othersources.anothersource ] ,
//...
```

I have collected all the data in a php file the way I want it. And the output of this page was a javascript with this

```php
 header('Content-Type: text/javascript');

$fromDB ="";
$sources = "sources = [";
foreach ($events as $value) { // value is source name
$fromDB .= "var $value = {
        url: path + 'fetchEvents.php',
        method: 'GET',
        extraParams: {
            value: $value, 
            code: new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get('code'),
        },
        failure: function(error) {
            console.log(error);
            Swal.fire('Error!', '', 'error');
        },
    };
";
$sources .= $value. " ";
}

$sources .= " ];";
// this $sources  give me 
// sources = [anothersource ,othersource ,anothersource2 ];
```

This make like this

```js
var anothersource = {
        url: path + 'fetchEvents.php',
        method: 'GET',
        extraParams: {
            value: $value, 
            code: new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get('code'),
        },
        failure: function(error) {
            console.log(error);
            Swal.fire('Error!', '', 'error');
        },
    };

var othersource = {
        url: path + 'fetchEvents.php',
        method: 'GET',
        extraParams: {
            value: $value, 
            code: new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get('code'),
        },
        failure: function(error) {
            console.log(error);
            Swal.fire('Error!', '', 'error');
        },
    };
var anothersource2 = {
        url: path + 'fetchEvents.php',
        method: 'GET',
        extraParams: {
            value: $value, 
            code: new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get('code'),
        },
        failure: function(error) {
            console.log(error);
            Swal.fire('Error!', '', 'error');
        },
    };

 sources = [anothersource ,othersource ,anothersource2 ];

.fullCalendar( {

  eventSources : sources , // here, we use dynamic eventsources

  viewDisplay : function( event ) {
     // assuming this will point to the full calendar,
     // might have to do something silly like
     // $( '#myCal' ).fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' );
     this.refetchEvents();
  }
} );
```

I added the main javascript file, which will do all the operations, at the bottom of this php file.

```php
//...
$file = "my/fullcalender/initjavascript/file.js"
 file_get_contents($file) . PHP_EOL;
//...
```

This code opens the javascript file in the $file path and takes whatever is in it and adds it to this file.

I hope that will be useful.