# Change Fullcalendar event source after render

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-1

I've been using FullCalendar v1.5.3 for a MS SharePoint replacement.

I'm trying to re-render the calendar event's source. For instance, when the page loads by default this is the ajax call

> /calendar/events/feedTasks?start=1338094800&end=1341118800&_=1339103302326

We're using a select box to change the events source to only show tasks (pulled from different table), so after a selection the ajax call changes to:

> /calendar/events/feedEvents?start=1338094800&end=1341118800&_=1339103302326

This works. However, rather than just changing the current calendar event source, it creates a duplicate calendar table (creates a new `div class="fc-content" div` on top of the current one).

This is what I have so far:

```
$("#TaskSelector").change(onSelectChange);   
    function onSelectChange(){
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            events: '/calendar/events/' + $('#TaskSelector').val()
        });
    }
});
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are some methods called `removeEventSource()` and `addEventSource()` that allow you to tweak the sources list. I had a similar situation where I needed to hide one of the sources in month view, but show it in other contexts, and I found removing and re-adding elements in the eventSources array the cleanest way to achieve this.

```
    var fcSources = {
        courses: {
                    url: base+'accessfm/calendar/courses',
                    type: 'GET',
                    cache: true,
                    error: function() { alert('something broke with courses...'); },
                    color: 'purple',
                    textColor: 'white',
                    className: 'course'
                },
        requests: {
                    url: base+'accessfm/calendar/requests',
                    type: 'GET',
                    cache: true,
                    error: function() { alert('something broke with requests...'); },
                    textColor: 'white',
                    className: 'requests'
                },
        loads:  {
                    url: base+'accessfm/calendar/loads',
                    type: 'GET',
                    cache: true,
                    error: function() { alert('something broke with loads...'); },
                    color: 'blue',
                    textColor: 'white',
                    className: 'loads'
                }
    };
<snip>
    $('#fullcalendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
                    left: 'title',
                    center: 'agendaDay,agendaWeek,month',
                    right: 'today prev,next'
                },
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
        firstDay: 1,
        theme: true,
        eventSources: [ fcSources.courses, fcSources.requests, fcSources.loads ],
        viewDisplay: function(view) {
            if (lastView != view.name){ // view has been changed, tweak settings
                if (view.name == 'month'){
                    $('#fullcalendar').fullCalendar( 'removeEventSource', fcSources.loads )
                                      .fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' );;
                }
                if (view.name != 'month' && lastView == 'month'){
                    $('#fullcalendar').fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', fcSources.loads );
                }
            }
            lastView = view.name;
        }
    });
```

Don't just copy/paste this code, because it's not solving exactly your problem. But you should be able to take some ideas from it. Tweak the `fcSources` hash to suit your sources, and then instantiate your fullCalendar object with just one of the sources, and swap it around using the `removeEventSource` and `addEventSource` methods.

Note also the use of `refetchEvents()` - that's necessary to make sure the display is rerendered correctly.

Comment: thanks for the reply. With your code I was able to come up with the following: 
  
      $("#TaskSelector").change(onSelectChange);     
 function onSelectChange(){  
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'removeEventSource', root + '/events/'+ defaultFeed ).fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' );  
  defaultFeed = $('#TaskSelector').val();  
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', root + '/events/' + defaultFeed ).fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' );  
 }  
});

It works good, but could you see any problems with it? I set defaultFeed at the top of the code, and so far so good.
Thanks for your reply!

Comment: @RET http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37204410/how-to-show-event-details-on-click-of-day-in-full-calendar can you please check this question?

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for this example :)

I was not able to make this ( in above code the events array ) work for me, but i figure out another way to add event sources using some of the code you provided.

This is my logic:

My primary source of events is this(this is the events source from the default examples of Fullcalendar):

```
events: function(start, end, callback) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'myurl',
                dataType:'xml',
                crossDomain: true,
                data: {
                    // our hypothetical feed requires UNIX timestamps
                    start: Math.round(start.getTime() / 1000),
                    end: Math.round(end.getTime() / 1000),                  
                    'acc':'2',                      
                },
                success: function(doc) {                            
                    var events = [];
                    var allday = null; //Workaround
                    var Editable = null; //Workaround  
                    $(doc).find('event').each(function() 
                    {                       
                        if($(this).attr('allDay') == "false") //Workaround 
                                allday = false; //Workaround 
                        if($(this).attr('allDay') == "true") //Workaround 
                                allday = true; //Workaround
                        if($(this).attr('editable') == "false") //Workaround 
                                Editable = false; //Workaround 
                        if($(this).attr('editable') == "true") //Workaround 
                                Editable = true; //Workaround                       

                        events.push({
                            id: $(this).attr('id'),
                            title: $(this).attr('title'),
                            start: $(this).attr('start'),
                            end: $(this).attr('end'),                       
                            allDay: allday,
                            editable: Editable
                        });                             
                    }); 


                    //calendar.fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', othersources.folgas );
                    //calendar.fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', othersources.ferias );       
                    //calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');               
                    callback(events);
                }
            });     
        }
```

Now i needed it to add more sources and to do this ouside the calendar (next to the date variables from fullcalendar examples) i made a variable like the code above, but with ajax calls similar to my primary: )

```
var othersources = {

   anothersource: {               
            events: function(start, end, callback) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'myurl',               
                data: {
                    // our hypothetical feed requires UNIX timestamps
                    start: Math.round(start.getTime() / 1000),
                    end: Math.round(end.getTime() / 1000),                  
                    'acc':'7',                      
                },          
                success: function(doc) {    

                    var events = [];
                    var allday = null; //Workaround
                    var Editable = null; //Workaround  
                    $(doc).find('event').each(function() 
                    {                       
                        if($(this).attr('allDay') == "false") //Workaround 
                                allday = false; //Workaround 
                        if($(this).attr('allDay') == "true") //Workaround 
                                allday = true; //Workaround
                        if($(this).attr('editable') == "false") //Workaround 
                                Editable = false; //Workaround 
                        if($(this).attr('editable') == "true") //Workaround 
                                Editable = true; //Workaround                       

                        events.push({
                            id: $(this).attr('id'),
                            title: $(this).attr('title'),
                            start: $(this).attr('start'),
                            end: $(this).attr('end'),                       
                            allDay: allday,
                            editable: Editable
                        });                             
                    });                         

                    callback(events); //notice this
                }
            });     

        },                
            cache: true,
            //error: function() { alert('something broke with courses...'); },
            color: 'green', //events color and stuff
            textColor: 'white',
            //className: 'course'
       }     
 }
```

The following code is similar to the above and is part of the calendar proprietys (inside calendar variable):

```
            eventSources: [ othersources.anothersource ],           

viewDisplay: function(view) {    
        if (view.name == 'month'){
       // alert(view.name);
            //calendar.fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', othersources.folgas );
            calendar.fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', othersources.anothersource );
            //calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents'); //Notice i'm not doing the refetch events. And its working for me. but i'm calling thi elsewhere, every time i make an action. So you must figure it out ;)           
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question but I was having a similar problem and RET's answer really helped, based on that I patched it with a counter that reset to make sure it wouldn't add duplicate event sources

```
    count = 0;
fcSources = [wholePlan, allActivities];

//calendar initialization {
viewRender: function(view) {

        if (view.name == 'agendaWeek' || view.name == 'month') {
            $('#fullcal').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', fcSources.allActivities);

            if (count > 0) {
                $('#fullcal').fullCalendar('addEventSource', fcSources.wholePlan);
            }

            count = 0;
        }

        if (view.name == 'agendaDay' && count == 0) {
            $('#fullcal').fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', fcSources.allActivities );
            $('#fullcal').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', fcSources.wholePlan);

            count += 1;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

after two days I got it, this is my code:

```
    $("#search").on("keypress", function(evt){
        if(evt.keyCode == 13) {
            var term = $(this).val();
            $.post(route_search, 
                            {
                                term: term,
                                async: false
                            },
                            function(data) {
                                var parsed = $.parseJSON(data);
                                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
                                $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', parsed );
                            }
            );               
        }
    });
```

There's a search input, when the user press enter key, an ajax post is sent to controller who returns an array os json values (events).
(sorry about my poor english)