# Fullcalendar, how to change passed parameter to eventSource dynamically?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I've a following code to get events:

```
    var eventSource = {
            url: 'api/events/get/byrange',
            data: {
                id: typeof($scope.calendar) == 'undefined' ? '1' : '2'
            }
    };
```

The problem that `typeof($scope.calendar) == 'undefined' ? '1' : '2'` evaluated only once, and all the following requests it passes a same `id`. How can I make it evaluate this expression again at every call?

Comment: Can you just create two sources and then programmatically show or hide them?  Similar to this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940182/change-fullcalendar-event-source-after-render

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write the

```
{
      url: 'api/events/get/byrange',
      data: {
           id: typeof($scope.calendar) == 'undefined' ? '1' : '2'
      }
};
```

Without setting it in a variable `var eventSource`. Instead just append that piece of code inside your FullCalendar initialization.

However, i don't use this method. Instead I perform a JSON request to an action which returns a list of objects.

Javascript:

```
$.getJSON('GetCalendar?TrainingId=' + $('#TrainingId').val(), function (response) {
    $('#CalendarWrapper').empty();
    $('#CalendarWrapper').append("<div id='calendar' name='calendar'></div>");
    window.events = response;
    window.calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay' //, basicWeek,basicDay
        },
        selectHelper: true,
        allDaySlot: false,
        slotDuration: '00:15:00',
        buttonIcons: true, // show the prev/next text
        weekNumbers: false,
        editable: true,
        selectOverlap: true,
        unselectAuto: true,
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        lang: GetFullCalendarLanguage(),
        aspectRatio: 2.5,
        events: window.events,
    });

    _CalendarBuild = true;
})
```

Action:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetCalendar(int TrainingId)
{
    var model = QUERY
        .Select(x => new FullCalendar
        {
            title = x.Module.Description + ", " + x.Local.Info,
            Day = x.Day,
            (...)
        })
        .ToList();

    return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

FullCalendar:

```
public class FullCalendar
{
    public virtual string title { get; set; }

    public virtual string url { get; set; }

    public virtual DateTime Day { get; set; }

    public virtual string start { get; set; }

    public virtual string end { get; set; }

    public virtual bool startEditable { get; set; }
}
```

And when I want to render again I just call the javascript again (that's placed inside a function).