# AngularJS FullCalendar - Events not loading on initial load

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, fullcalendar

### Issue

---

I am struggling to get my events to populate the Full Calendar on load. The events work fine when I change the month, but when the application first loads they don't seem to appear.

### Code

---

Here is my code for for the `UIConfig` of the Calendar:

```
//THIS CALLS MY GET METHOD.
var holidaysnew = getUserEventsById.getUserEventsById();

$scope.uiConfig = {
    calendar: {
        viewRender: function (view, element) {
            holidaysnew.forEach(function (hol) {

                $scope.eventSources[0].events.push({
                    end: $filter('dateFilter')(hol.HOLIDAY_END),
                    start: $filter('dateFilter')(hol.HOLIDAY_START),
                    title: hol.HOLIDAY_TITLE,
                    color: $filter('colorEventFilter')(hol.HOLIDAY_EVENT_STATE_ID)
                });
            });
        },
        height: 850,
        editable: true,
        header: {
            left: '',
            center: '',
            right: ''
        },
    }
};
```

Now the `viewRender` gets hit on load aswell as when I change the month. The weird thing is it only works when you click a new month.

Comment: can you create a demo of your problem on jsfiddle.net or plnkr.co ?

Comment: @HenriqueC. As my `$http.get` is done in the service folder? So how would I implement this?

Comment: @BenClarke check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940182/change-fullcalendar-event-source-after-render/16340565#16340565

Answer (score 1):

@Ben problem is that you are making http call in service. But here calendar will not wait for http response. So calendar loads first then after you will receive http response that's why you are not getting response first time. You need to change the way to load events like below.

```
$scope.uiConfig = {
    calendar: {
        events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {

            $http({
                method  : "GET",
                url     : 'your_url_to_fatch_events',
                data    : {start: startDate, end: endDate, id: userId}
            }).then(
                function (olidaysnew) {
                    var events = [];
                    // or make your events
                    olidaysnew.forEach(function (hol) {
                        events.push({
                            end: $filter('dateFilter')(hol.HOLIDAY_END),
                            start: $filter('dateFilter')(hol.HOLIDAY_START),
                            title: hol.HOLIDAY_TITLE,
                            color: $filter('colorEventFilter')(hol.HOLIDAY_EVENT_STATE_ID)
                        });

                    )}
                    callback(events);
                }
            )
        },
        height: 850,
        editable: true,
        header: {
            left: '',
            center: '',
            right: ''
        },
    }
}
```