# FullCalendar v3 - Change Event Source on View Change

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I'm using FullCalendar v3 (latest) with a PHP backend.

I'm returning a JSON array from the backend broken up into 2 arrays. The first contains event details (a list of orders for the day, with the order# as the title), and the second contains a daily summary (with a sum of orders and work hours as the title). The array looks like this:

```
{"events":[{"id":709989,"item_no":"ABC123","title":709989,"color":"red","start":"2019-05-14","end":"2019-05-14","allDay":true,"total_hours":3,"remaining_hours":1.5},{"id":709990,"title":709990,"item_no":"ABC345","color":"red","start":"2019-05-15","end":"2019-05-15","allDay":true,"total_hours":5.7,"remaining_hours":3.2}],"summary":[{"id":338823,"title":"Orders: 14\rHours:28.33\rRemaining Hours:13.33","start":"2019-05-14","end":"2019-05-14","allDay":true},{"id":338824,"title":"Orders: 3\rHours:14.2\rRemaining Hours: 12.2","start":"2019-05-15","end":"2019-05-15","allDay":true}]}
```

There are other properties but these are the basics.

What I'm trying to do is change the array that's used as the event source depending upon which view is selected. I've tried custom event rendering, custom view rendering, multiple event sources (even though it's expensive from a data point-of-view, the # of records aren't so numerous that it greatly effects performance).

The custom view name is customMonth. When this view is selected, I just want to render the summary data (from the summary array). If any of the other views are selected (I'm using basicWeek, month and listWeek), render the events array.

```
let vname;
$("#calendar").fullCalendar({
    defaultDate: new Date(),
    defaultView: 'month',
    eventRender: function(eventObj, $el, view) {
        let n = view.name;
        if(n=='customMonth')
        {
            vname = 'customMonth';
            $el.popover({
                title: eventObj.title,
                content: eventObj.total_hours,
                html: true,
                trigger: 'hover',
                placement: 'auto',
                container: 'body'
            });
        } else {
            vname = n;
            $el.popover({
                title: "Work Order " + eventObj.title,
                content: '<strong>Item#</strong>: ' + eventObj.item_no + '<br />' + '<strong>Total Hours</strong>: ' + eventObj.total_hours + '<br />' + '<strong>Remaining Hours</strong>: ' + eventObj.remaining_hours,
                html: true,
                trigger: 'hover',
                placement: 'auto',
                container: 'body'
            });
        }
    }, 
    events: function(start, end, timezone, callback){
        $.ajax({
            url: '/myendpoint',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                action: 'get-calendar-summary',
                cell: selected_cell
            },
            success: function(data) {
                let events = [];
                if(vname=='customMonth') {
                    obj = data.summary;
                    $(obj).each(function() {
                        events.push({
                            id: $(this).attr('id'),
                            title: $(this).attr('title'),
                            start: $(this).attr('dept_due_dt'),
                            end: $(this).attr('dept_due_dt'),
                            total_hours: $(this).attr('total_hours'),
                            remaining_hours: $(this).attr('remaining_hours'),
                            order_count: $(this).attr('day_order_count'),
                            has_late_order: $(this).attr('has_late_order'),
                            allDay: true,
                            earliest_date: $(this).attr('earliest_date')
                        });
                    });
                } else {
                    obj = data.event_results;
                    $(obj).each(function() {
                        events.push({
                            id: $(this).attr('id'),
                            color: $(this).attr('color'),
                            title: $(this).attr('title'),
                            start: $(this).attr('start'),
                            end: $(this).attr('end'),
                            earliest_date: $(this).attr('earliest_date'),
                            item_no: $(this).attr('item_no'),
                            total_hours: $(this).attr('total_hours'),
                            remaining_hours: $(this).attr('remaining_hours')
                        });
                    });
                }
                callback(events);
            },
            error: function(err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    },
    views: {
        customMonth: {
            type: 'month',
            buttonText: 'overview'
        }
    },
    viewRender: function(view, el) {
        let lastview;
        if(view.name=='customMonth') {
            if(lastview == 'customMonth') {
                return false;
            } else {
                view.unrenderDates();
                view.renderDates();
                $("#calendar").fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
            }
            lastview = 'customMonth';
        } else {
            if(lastview=='customMonth') {
                view.unrenderDates();
                view.renderDates();
                $("#calendar").fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
            }
            lastview = view.name;
        }
    },
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'basicWeek,month,listWeek,customMonth'
    },
    themeSystem: 'bootstrap3',
    timeZone: false,
    weekends: false,
    //tried with and without lazyFetching
    lazyFetching: true
});
```

I'd appreciate any guidance. I've searched StackOverflow ([this seems like the closest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940182/change-fullcalendar-event-source-after-render), but I followed exactly and it didn't work (switching out viewDisplay for viewRender)),  Github, and all other sources I can think of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here a simplified example of what you are trying to achieve (I hope I well understand your problem) :

HTML :

```
 <div id='calendar'></div>
```

---

Javascript :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var ev1 = {"events":[{"id":709989,"item_no":"ABC123","title":'Event from source 1',"color":"red","start":"2019-05-14","end":"2019-05-14","allDay":true,"total_hours":3,"remaining_hours":1.5}]};
    var ev2 = {"events":[{"id":709989,"item_no":"ABC123","title":'Event from source 2',"color":"blue","start":"2019-05-14","end":"2019-05-14","allDay":true,"total_hours":3,"remaining_hours":1.5}]};
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        defaultDate: new Date(),
        defaultView: 'month',
        viewRender: function(view) {
          if(view.type === 'basicWeek') {
             $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'removeEventSource', ev1 );
             $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', ev2 );
             return; 
           }  
        },
        header: {
           left: 'prev,next',
           center: 'title',
           right: 'basicWeek,month,listWeek,customMonth'
        },

    });
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', ev1 );  
});
```

**And the [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qGqMpb) to try it.**

It uses the callback function `viewRender()` to detect when a view change and `addEventSource()`/`removeEventSource()` to change the data. So when you change the view from `month` to `week` it will change the source events.

Comment: I've been fighting with this for 2 days because I didn't include a return in the viewRender function?!? I was able to modify the code in the answer to work with my AJAX sources and it's working!  Can you help me understand why the return is necessary? Thank you so much @UgoT.

Comment: For anyone else with this issue: in each sources object I had an AJAX success function that iterated over the events and pushed them into an events array, which I then returned. I removed the success function from the object as well.