# How to Add/remove the event source of Full Calendar on checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, fullcalendar

I am trying to add/remove the event sources of full Calendar depending on which checkbox

This is my checkbox and calendar.

```
<div class="x_content">
   <div class="row">
      {% for key,val in mydict.items %}
      <label class="checkbox-inline" style="margin: 5px;">
      <input class="email_id" type="checkbox" id="{{key}}" value = "{{key}}">{{key}}
      </label>
      {% endfor %}
   </div>
   <div class="clearfix"></div>
   <br>
   <div id="calendar"></div>
</div>
```

This is my javascript added in html.

```
<script>

    var eventSourceName = new Array();
    var eventSourceData = new Array();
    var i = 0;

    {% for key,val in mydict.items %}
    eventSourceName[i] = "{{key}}";
    eventSourceData[i] = [

    {% for dt in val %}
    {
      "title": "{{dt.title}}",
      "start": "{{dt.start}}",
      "end": "{{dt.end}}",
      "id": "{{dt.id}}",
      "color": "{{dt.color}}",
    },
    {% endfor %}

    ];
    i = i+1;
    {% endfor %}

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
      var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
      var currentDate = new Date();
      var day = currentDate.getDate();
      var month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1;
      var year = currentDate.getFullYear();
      current_date = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
      var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
        initialDate: currentDate,
        headerToolbar: {
          left: 'prev,next today',
          center: 'title',
          right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
        },
        editable: true,
        slotMinTime: "07:00:00",
        slotMaxTime: "20:00:00",
        eventSources:[
        ]
          });

    calendar.render();
        });

    jQuery(function(){
      $("input.email_id").click(function(){
        $("input.email_id:checked").each(function(){
          var temp = $(this).val();
          for(let i = 0;i<eventSourceName.length;i++){
            if(eventSourceName[i] === temp){
              $('#calender').fullCalendar('addEventSource',eventSourceData[i]);
            }
          }
        });
        
      });
    });


   
  </script>
```

I have eventSourceName and its corresponding data. mycheckbox has same value as eventSourcename. So if I click on checkbox then corresponding eventSourceData need to be added.
After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940182/change-fullcalendar-event-source-after-render), I added `$('#calender').fullCalendar('addEventSource',eventSourceData[i]);`   so that new eventsource can be added but I get the error
`(index):3413 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fullCalendar is not a function`.
Where I am going wrong?

Note - When I am adding eventSourceData in eventSources like `eventSources:[eventSourceData[0],eventSourceData[1],eventSourceData[2]]`. I can see all the events in my calendar.

Comment: `Where I am going wrong`... because fullCalendar (since version 4) isn't a jQuery plugin, so . fullCalendar isn't a method you can call on a jQuery object. That example you found is very old and refers specifically to version 1

Comment: Check the official documentation for up to date information... https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-addEventSource

Comment: No problem. Any reason you didn't do that already when your example failed to work?

Comment: I was looking at Docs version 3 and did not realize that its older version. in the older version `.fullCalendar( ‘addEventSource’, source )`,  is mentioned.

Comment: Ah ok. Yeah always check the version!